# Using <div> for layout

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use `<div>` tags instead of tables to design the layout of my website. Everything works fine except the layout of the "content" area. The left side is an `<ul>`, then an `<img>` (used to divide the left list from the content, should always separate the `<ul>` from the text), then the text. I want all of these to be in the same line. I'm not sure on where to go from here.

```css
html {
  color: white;
}
body {
  background-image: url("images/background.jpg");
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  text-size: 100%;
}
#container {
  background-color: rgb(18, 18, 18);
  max-width: 90%;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  opacity: 0.85;
}
img.border {
  border: 1px solid DarkKhaki;
  width: 110px;
  height: 83px;
}
/* Header */

#header {
  max-width: 100%;
  line-height: 112px;
  position: relative;
}
#logo {
  float: left;
  line-height: 112px;
}
img#logoPic {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 6px;
}
#top_info {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25px;
  left: 115px;
  line-height: 112px;
}
#topHeaderText {
  font-size: 2.3em;
  display: inline-block;
}
/* End Header */

/* Top Navigation Bar */

#topNavBar {
  clear: both;
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-top: 2px solid DarkKhaki;
  border-bottom: 2px solid DarkKhaki;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
#topNavBar ul {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 20px 0;
}
#topNavBar li {
  display: inline;
}
#topNavBar li a {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 1.2em;
}
#topNavBar a:hover {
  color: DarkKhaki;
}
/* End Navigation Bar */

/* Content Area */

#content_area {
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.7;
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 2px solid DarkKhaki;
}
#content_header {
  color: DarkKhaki;
  text-align: center;
}
#content_Text {
  text-align: center;
}
<!-- Side Navigation Bar --> #sideNavBar {
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}
ul#sideNav {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ul#sideNav li {
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 7px
}
ul#sideNav a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 3px 3px;
}
ul#sideNav a:hover {
  color: DarkKhaki;
}
#divider {
  max-height: 100%;
  float: left;
  display: inline;
}
#content_Text {
  text-align: center;
}
<!-- End Side Navigation Bar --> #project_thumbs {
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
table.projectThumbTable {
  text-align: center;
  border: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
}
table.projectThumbTable td {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}
table.projectThumbTable p:hover {
  color: DarkKhaki;
}
p.thumbInfo {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: underline;
  font-size: 15px;
}
/* End Content Area */

/* Footer */

#footer {
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.7;
  max-width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-left: 2px solid DarkKhaki;
  border-top: 2px solid DarkKhaki;
  border-right: 2px solid DarkKhaki;
}
#footer p {
  font-size: .7em;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 3px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
/* End Footer */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Danny Steveson Portfolio</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="DannyStevesonPortfolio.css" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/titleLogo.png" />
</head>

<body>
  <!-- Container -->
  <div id="container">
    <!-- Header -->
    <div id="header">
      <div id="logo">
        <a href="default.html" title="Home Page">
          <img src="images/logo.png" id="logoPic" alt="Logo">
        </a>
      </div>
      <div id="top_info">
        <span id="topHeaderText">Danny Steveson Portfolio</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End Header -->
    <!-- Navigation Bar -->
    <div id="topNavBar">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="webDesign.html">Web Design</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="gameDesign.html">Game Design</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="databases.html">Databases</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="resume.html">Resume</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <br />
    <!-- End Navigation Bar -->
    <!-- Content Area -->
    <div id="content_area">
      <div id="sideNavBar">
        <ul id="sideNav">
          <li><a href="WDprogrammingEd.html" style="color:DarkKhaki">Description</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="WDprogrammingEdHTML.html">HTML</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="WDprogrammingEdCSS.html">CSS</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="WDprogrammingEdJavaScript.html">JavaScript</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="WDprogrammingEdSQL.html">SQL</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div id="divider">
        <img src="images/contentDivider.jpg" />
      </div>
      <div id="content_header">
        <h1>Programming Education</h1>
      </div>
      <div id="project_thumbs">
        <p id="contentText">
          In order to build upon my current knowledge of programming, I have
          <br />a simple website that describes the basics of programming languages.
          <br />The website contains examples of basic coding concepts and also shows
          <br />how the code was implemented into the page itself. I followed
          <br />W3schools.com for the basic information and table of contents.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br />
    <!-- End Content Area -->
    <!-- Footer -->
    <div id="footer">
      <p>Created by: Danny Steveson 2015</p>
    </div>
    <!-- End Footer -->
    <!-- END Container -->
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

[image: This is my current result]

[image: This is what I want it to look like]

Comment: A lot of this can be drastically simplified... you use a lot of nested elements, which adds needless complication. [Here is a basic example I created for you](https://jsbin.com/waciki/edit?html,css,output). Generally you should avoid using HTML for style, so things like `<div id="divider">
        <img src="images/contentDivider.jpg" />
      </div>` should not be used. (This is also making it hard for you to line your nav and content up on the same line.

Comment: Thank you very much. Seems to work out much better but I will have to look at this tomorrow. Got overwhelmed today just trying things.

Comment: This is excellent. I am re-designing my website now because your response also answered about ten other questions that I was going to have trouble with. Thank you for taking the time to answer this!

Comment: No worries :) Now, w3schools can sometimes be pretty rubbish/outdated, so use some good resources like css-tricks (some excellent techniques there), w3.org (the official documentation, a bit confusing), the Mozilla Development Network (MDN), Smashing Magazine (quality articles) and html5 doctor (if you can't quite figure out what html5 element to use and where). Also, it's amazingly common for some people to use really basic text editors like notepad for their web development. If this is you, then you could try the awesome, open source [Brackets](http://brackets.io/) which is brilliant :)